# What happens if you change the order of operations?

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers

I learned about PEMDAS and all that in elementary school. I know that PEMDAS is pretty much just a convention, but it is a convention I cannot integrate into the rest of my mathematical knowledge. Any specific reason why PEMDAS was chosen the way it was chosen? What would happen if we chose any other convention? Would math change drastically, if yes how, if no why not?

Comment: It is just the natural way. E.g. your room may measure 12 square meters. You have written this as $12 \,qm$ or $12\,m^2$ long before you knew that it is actually $12 \cdot m^2.$ PEDMAS follows everyday language. Any other order, e.g. polish notation would require relearning something, which is always a source for mistakes and in a case like this, unnecessary.

Comment: Nothing would happen, possibly we would have a harder time writing the things we do.

Comment: I would have to rewrite the parser in my maths expression evaluation tool. Not good.